# If EXP = NEXP, can we say anything about P and NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, p-vs-np

I found one older question asked about this but without any responses.

Comment: Try using the method of padding.

Comment: Why was this marked as a duplicate? The linked question does not have any answers. To Yuval - the padding argument works to show the converse but I don't see how it can be used in this case. To Raphael - this isn't a homework problem. I was just unable to find any theorems about it.